# How to drive a car in snow

Tags: driving

What is the recommended way of driving a car in snow in the USA ?

I have lived in Southern USA all my life and have seen very little snow fall(once in a decade). Which doesn't even stick on the road and melts away real fast. From whatever is left, apart from the car slipping a little on the road and the brakes not being as responsive as they are, I don't really remember anything about how it is to drive in snow. 
I am making [road trip vacation plans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20285/4584) and I want to know how I can stay prepared, as far as travelling by road is concerned, if we travel in months when it snows. If it helps, I will be driving either a Ford F 150 or a F 250 which has regular tires. Do I need to buy chains for my tires ? Can one rent such 'snow-tires' ?